# Issue Converting react class components to functional components with state is undefined

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-component, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks

Can life cycles be used in Arrow functions using componentDidMount() and having an error my only response I tried to add a useEffect ?  Trying to Converting class components to functional components.
I created a contentful blog in a separate project below and would like to add my blog to my blog.js page in my main project.

Original contentful blog that works.

Blog.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { client } from "./client";
import Posts from "./components/blog/Posts";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    client
      .getEntries()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          articles: response.items,
        });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <header>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <span>React and Content</span>
            </div>
          </header>
          <main>
            <div className="blog__page">
              <h1 class="blog__page__header">ZILAH MUSIC PUBLISHING NEWS</h1>
              <div className="blogs">
                <div className="wrapper">
                  <Posts posts={this.state.articles} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

I added a useEffect and now my state is undefined

```
 useEffect(() => {
    client
      .getEntries()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          articles: response.items,
        });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
```

I duplicated my previous running pages and would like to include my blog but I have an issue converting[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wub5c.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { client } from "../../client";
import Posts from "../../components/blog/Posts";

import "./Blog.css";

class App extends React.Component inside an arrow function

const Blog = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }


useEffect(() => {
        client
          .getEntries()
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
              articles: response.items,
            });
          })
          .catch(console.error);
      }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
          <header>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <span>React and Content</span>
            </div>
          </header>
          <main>
            <div className="blog__page">
              <h1 className="blog__page__header">
                ZILAH MUSIC PUBLISHING NEWS
              </h1>
              <div className="blogs">
                <div className="wrapper">
                  <Posts posts={this.state.articles} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

Bog.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Blog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Function components use the `useState` hook instead of `this.setState` and `this.state` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

At the top of your function component, add this (make sure to import `useState` from 'react' like you did with `useEffect`):

```
const Blog = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  //... etc
```

Then, instead of `this.setState()` use:

```
setArticles(response.items);
```

And, in the body:

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <Posts posts={articles} />
</div>
```

*The title of your post (expected parameter accessToken) seems unrelated to the problem you mention part way through saying that your state is undefined, which is what this answer addresses*

Comment: Do you mean to add <Posts posts={articles} /> in place of <Posts posts={this.state.articles} />

Comment: Yes -- you will no longer be able to refer to `this.state` in function components.

Comment: Still doesn't work having an error React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. I sttill recieve an error of React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally.

Comment: You've put it at the wrong place. Look at my example -- it should directly follow the line `const Blog = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {`

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code
and recieved this error.
src\components\layout\Blog.js
Line 16:35:  React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?   react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Line 18:3:   React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { client } from "../../client";
import Posts from "../../components/blog/Posts";

import "./Blog.css";
import BlogConnect from "./BlogConnect";

const Blog = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    client
      .getEntries()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setArticles(response.items);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <header>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <span>React and Content</span>
            </div>
          </header>
          <main>
            <div className="blog__page">
              <h1 className="blog__page__header">
                ZILAH MUSIC PUBLISHING NEWS
              </h1>
              <div className="blogs">
                <div className="wrapper">
                  <Posts posts={articles} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

Blog.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Blog);
```

Comment: You should edit your post -- not add this as an answer. The useState line needs to go at the *top* of the function component, before `if (isAuthenticated)`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate your help to simplify the problem so i can understand.

Comment: my issue with the componentDidMount() and useeffect is solved but i have a new a new  error of Expected parameter accessToken

Comment: You aren't showing any code with accessToken in it. If my answer solved the initial question, I would ask that you accept the answer (the green checkmark) and then start a new question showing the code necessary to illustrate the other problem.

Comment: I checked the (the green checkmark) and added a new questions. thanks for your help again new to the platform and getting a custom to it.

Comment: Hmm -- my answer isn't showing up as accepted to me